# Trying to place list using li to the left with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place the li to the left.
When I use `float:right;` it removes the Background color, and it gets ugly
Please help me to place the li to the left?

### html:

```
<div class="internallinks2">                  
                          <h2>More categories</h2>

                        <ul id="MoreCategoriesUL">
                          <li class="MoreCategoriesLI">
                            <i class="fas fa-table-tennis"></i>
                            <a href="HowTo_computes_cat.html"style="padding:10px; 
                            width:20px;">Entertainment</a>
                            <br>
                          </li>

                        </ul>
</div>
```

---

### css:

```
.internallinks2 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #767676;
  background-color: #f6f5f4;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 80px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#MoreCategoriesUL {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}
#MoreCategoriesUL li {
  clear: both;
  list-style-image: none;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Also any pic there for expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is put li to left with margin and padding

```
     #MoreCategoriesUL {
            list-style: none;
            margin-left: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

     #MoreCategoriesUL li {
            list-style-image: none;
            float: left;
            background: red;
            display: block;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

    #MoreCategoriesUL:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: what type of background you using?

check this: https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/rNaxrPB

Comment: I am talking about the entire ul background , i don't need background for ui.http://floomby.io/s/091219/bVOswNN5?a , the white background

Comment: #MoreCategoriesUL:after {
     content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    }

add this for fix background

Comment: vote this answer and accept ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
.internallinks2 {
  z-index: 99;
  /* Other CSS Attributes */
}
```

I'm not sure since I can't visualize the problem, but this may help.

Comment: why can't you?, open my code in any program or chrome , and you can clearly see when you float:right they background dissapear, unfortntually your methord didnt help me!